# Python Bag of Words NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Tags: python, twitter, nlp

I have been following this site, https://radimrehurek.com/data_science_python/, to apply bag of words on a list of tweets.

```
import csv
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas

messages = pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/Suki/Project/Project12/newData1.csv', sep='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
                               names=["label", "message"])

def split_into_tokens(message):
    message = unicode(message, encoding="utf8")  # convert bytes into proper unicode
    return TextBlob(message).words

messages.message.head().apply(split_into_tokens)

print (messages)
```

However I keep getting this error. I've checked and I following the code on the site but the error keeps arising.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Suki/Project/Project12/projectBagofWords.py", line 34, in <module>
    messages.message.head().apply(split_into_tokens)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2510, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1521, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:/Users/Suki/Project/Project12/projectBagofWords.py", line 31, in split_into_tokens
    message = unicode(message, encoding="utf8")  # convert bytes into proper unicode
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Can someone offer advice on how I could rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unicode is python 2.x method. If you are running Python 3.x, then all strings are unicode and that call is not needed.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was unaware it was Python 2 as I only recently started with Python and with 3. After rectifying the error I had initially I've stumbled into another error following the code. Is it a common occurrence when trying to use Python 2 with 3?

Answer (score 5):

`unicode` is a python 2 method. If you are not sure which version will run this code, you can simply add this at the beginning of your code so it will replace the old `unicode` with new `str`:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    unicode = str
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll use it from now on.